# Continuity of functions of several variables

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

trying to understand this example of continuity of a a function on $R^2$

$$f(x,y) := \begin{cases}
    \frac{xy^2}{x^2 + y^2}& \text{if } (x,y) \neq (0,0)\\
    0              & \text{if } (x,y) = (0,0)
\end{cases}
$$

to prove continuity at (0,0) we need to show:

$$ \left|{\frac{x_ny_n^2}{x_n^2 + y_n^2} - 0}\right| = \left|{\frac{x_ny_n^2}{x_n^2 + y_n^2}}\right|  \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0 ~~~~~~~~~
\text{whenever} (x_n, y_n) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} (0,0)
$$

can someone explain the above criterion, I am struggling to make sense of it. 
The definition of continuity states $ \lim_{x \to x_0}  f(x) = f(x_0)  $ In this case $x_0~~ is ~~(0,0),$ we need to show that the limit from every direction is approaching $f(x_0)$. Is that right?

Thanks for the answers, I get the idea when x, y are scalar variables, but in the text they are vectors defined on a set $D \subset R^n$ with values in $R^k $  and my text has 3 conditions out of which one needs to be satisfied to prove continuity.

1. using the epsilon-delta definition
2. if every component function $f_i~~of ~~ \pmb{f} = (f_1, ...., f_k) $ is continuous at $x_0$
3. $\pmb{f}(x_n) \to \pmb{f}(x_0)$ as $ n \to \infty $ for every sequence $x_n$ in D for which $x_n \to {x_0}$

I believe it is the 3rd option they are using in the text for the above question and that is the one I am having most difficulty understanding. Can someone please explain the 3rd criterion in plain english.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. To show it, you can divide both numerator and denominator by $y_n^2$.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely don't "need to show" this. Introducing sequences into the game just complicates matters and adds at least two additional nested quantifiers to the definition of limit.

You have to show that for any $\epsilon>0$ you can find a $\delta>0$ such that $r:=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$ implies $|f(x,y)|<\epsilon$. Expressing $f$ in polar coordinates we have
$$\tilde f(r,\phi):=f(r\cos\phi,r\sin\phi)={r^3\cos\phi\sin^2\phi\over r^2}=r\cos\phi\sin^2\phi\qquad(r>0)\ .$$
It follows that $|\tilde f(r,\phi)|\leq r$, so that $\delta:=\epsilon$ is an allowed choice.